# Subtraction of elements column-wise, in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
frame=pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,5,9,4,7,3],"col2":[5,8,7,9,3,4],"col3":[3,4,2,7,9,1],
          "col4":[2,4,7,4,9,0],"col5":[3,4,5,2,1,1],"col6":[8,7,5,4,1,2]})
```

it results in the following output:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
0     1       5      3       2        3       8
1     5       8      4       4        4       7
2     9       7      2       7        5       5
3     4       9      7       4        2       4
4     7       3      9       9        1       1
5     3       4      1       0        1       2
```

I want to create a new dataframe that differences col1 and col2, col3 and col4 and col5 and col6

Expected output is like that:

```
    col1-col2   col3-col4   col5-col6
0      -4           1           -5
1      -3           0           -3
2       2          -5            0
3      -5           3           -2
4       4           0            0
5      -1           1           -1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If many columns use general solution - select pair and unpair columns, convert to numpy array and create new `DataFrame` by contructor:

```
#pandas 0.24+
arr = frame.iloc[:, ::2].to_numpy() - frame.iloc[:, 1::2].to_numpy()
#pandas below
#arr = frame.iloc[:, ::2].values - frame.iloc[:, 1::2].values

c = [f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in zip(frame.columns[::2], frame.columns[1::2])]
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=c)
print (df)
   col1-col2  col3-col4  col5-col6
0         -4          1         -5
1         -3          0         -3
2          2         -5          0
3         -5          3         -2
4          4          0          0
5         -1          1         -1
```

If performance is important, convert to numpy array first, store to variable and then indexing:

```
#pandas 0.24+
arr = frame.to_numpy()
#pandas below
#arr = frame.values
c = [f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in zip(frame.columns[::2], frame.columns[1::2])]
df = pd.DataFrame(arr[:, ::2] - arr[:, 1::2], columns=c)
```

Comment: @yatu - ya, double .values vs only once, it should be interesing see difference in performance...

Comment: Yeah interesting `.values` is quite costly. There's a good improvement there (200us). Nice +1

Answer (score 4):

```
dfr = pd.DataFrame({'col1-col2': frame.col1 - frame.col2,
                    'col3-col4': frame.col3 - frame.col4,
                    'col5-col6': frame.col5 - frame.col6})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(frame.apply(lambda x: [x['col1']-x['col2'],x['col3']-x['col4'],x['col5']-x['col6']],axis=1).tolist())
df.rename({0:'col1-col2',1:'col3-col4',2:'col4-col5'},axis=1)
```

---

```
   col1-col2  col3-col4  col4-col5
0         -4          1         -5
1         -3          0         -3
2          2         -5          0
3         -5          3         -2
4          4          0          0
5         -1          1         -1
```